# Symfony2: "Remember me" tries to authenticate by username instad of email

Tags: php, symfony, remember-me

I have an application with user authenticaton against database. The property I use is email:

```
    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: 
              class: CorabMainBundle:User
              property: email
```

Authentication works great!
But I have huge problems getting the remember me functionality to work. 
After several hours I think I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it...

Symfony2 seems to try to authenticate with the username instead of email in case of remember me.

dev.log says the following:

```
[2013-10-21 23:49:19] security.DEBUG: Remember-me cookie detected. [] []
[2013-10-21 23:49:19] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.salt AS salt3, t0.password AS password4, t0.email AS email5, t0.is_active AS is_active6, t0.organisation AS organisation7 FROM User t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 ["roger"] []
[2013-10-21 23:49:19] security.INFO: User for remember-me cookie not found. [] []
[2013-10-21 23:49:19] security.DEBUG: Clearing remember-me cookie "REMEMBERME" [] []
```

Line 2 is not ok beacuse it should not be **roger** but an **email address**. That's why the cookie gets deleted.

How to tell symfony2 to use email as property for remember me authentication?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend the default remember me service class and override the onLoginSuccess method so it uses the email instead of the username.

- Service to be extended: **security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.class**
- Class: **Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices**
- Method: **onLoginSuccess**

Comment: I’ve been trying to do this in Symfony 4 but I’m getting a `You have requested a non-existent service "security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.class”` . why is that? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Or you can return the e-mail on the getUsername() function and change the name of your real username field like "nickname"..

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

When you implement the *UserInterface*, the comment on *UserInterface.php* say

```
/**
 * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
 *
 * @return string The username
 */
public function getUsername();
```

Yes it is "bad" but less verbose. The real problem is this damn function name. Symfony2 should change it..

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have just modify the "rememberme" cookie and replace the username by the email like this:

```
if(userJustLogin) {
    // decode cookie
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $cookies = $request->cookies->all();
    $cookieParts = explode(':', base64_decode($cookies["REMEMBERME"]));

    // replace username by email and update hash
    list($class, $username, $expires, $hash) = $cookieParts;
    $cookieParts[1] = base64_encode($user->getMail());
    $cookieParts[3] = hash_hmac('sha256', $class.$user->getMail().$expires.$user->getPassword(), 'YourSecretTokenFromParameters.yml');

    // reencode cookie
    $cookies["REMEMBERME"] = base64_encode(implode(':', $cookieParts));
    $cookie = new Cookie('REMEMBERME', $cookies["REMEMBERME"], $expires);

    // send new cookie
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
    $response->send();
}
```