# Symfony FOSUserBundle Remeber me doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, remember-me, symfony-3.2

I'm using FOSUserBundle with email as username.

Tryin' to use the remember_me functionality but it's not working. I've read this [Symfony2: "Remember me" tries to authenticate by username instad of email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505555/symfony2-remember-me-tries-to-authenticate-by-username-instad-of-email)

It's quite an old article and the username field in the database is set with the same value as the email so i don't understand why it is not working.

Checking with Google Chrome Inspector the REMEMBERME cookie is set...

Can someone help?

This is my security.yaml

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a *role* configuration problem.

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully):

- **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY**: All users (even anonymous ones) have this
- **IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED**: All logged in users have this, even if they are logged in because of a "remember me cookie". Even if you 
  don't use the remember me functionality, you can use this to check if
  the user is logged in.
- **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY**: This is similar to IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, but stronger. Users who are logged in
  only because of a "remember me cookie" will have
  IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED but will not have IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY.

So, in my security.yml, trying to access to path "^/$" and "^/account/*" after closing the browser was not possible because of the **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY** request.

I've changed it into this

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/*, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Now i can access to "^/$" path with the REMEMBERME cookie but not to "^/account/*" and "^/admin/*" that are more restrictive because of the sensitive data (and it's exactly what i wanted).